# How to clean a dataset in R from uci

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following function :

```
data_preprocessing<-function(link){
  
link=as.character(link) 
dataset=read.csv(link)  
dataset=replace(dataset,dataset=="?",NA)  

return(dataset)

}
```

Example ( https protocole problem ) :

```
Echocardiogram=data_preprocessing("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data")
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

After downloading the dataset :

```
Echocardiogram=data_preprocessing("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data")

head(Echocardiogram)

    X11   X0    X71 X0.1 X0.260     X9 X4.600    X14    X1  X1.1 name X1.2 X0.2
1    19    0     72    0  0.380      6  4.100     14 1.700 0.588 name    1    0
2    16    0     55    0  0.260      4  3.420     14     1     1 name    1    0
3    57    0     60    0  0.253 12.062  4.603     16 1.450 0.788 name    1    0
4    19    1     57    0  0.160     22  5.750     18 2.250 0.571 name    1    0
5    26    0     68    0  0.260      5  4.310     12     1 0.857 name    1    0
6    13    0     62    0  0.230     31  5.430   22.5 1.875 0.857 name    1    0
```

Also :

```
str(Echocardiogram)
'data.frame':   130 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ X11   : Factor w/ 57 levels "",".03",".25",..: 18 16 54 18 27 14 50 18 26 12 ...
 $ X0    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","?","0","1": 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ X71   : Factor w/ 40 levels "","?","35","46",..: 30 12 17 14 26 19 17 4 11 34 ...
 $ X0.1  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X0.260: Factor w/ 74 levels "","?","0.010",..: 65 50 47 26 50 42 59 60 21 19 ...
 $ X9    : Factor w/ 93 levels "","?","0","10",..: 69 57 13 46 62 56 79 3 19 29 ...
 $ X4.600: Factor w/ 106 levels "","?","2.32",..: 25 6 54 92 38 85 76 70 47 33 ...
 $ X14   : Factor w/ 48 levels "","?","10","10.5",..: 16 16 21 27 8 36 16 21 19 27 ...
 $ X1    : Factor w/ 67 levels "","?","1","1.04",..: 48 3 37 60 3 52 3 11 16 50 ...
 $ X1.1  : Factor w/ 32 levels "","?","0.140",..: 14 30 25 13 27 27 30 31 29 21 ...
 $ X1.2  : Factor w/ 5 levels "","?","1","2",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ X0.2  : Factor w/ 5 levels "","?","0","1",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 ...
```

Here , i'm wanting to replace all `"?"` in the dataset with `NA`. Also , it will be good to remove duplicated and empty rows ( like the 50 row  ).

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table::fread("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data", 
                        fill = TRUE,
                        na.strings = "?")
```

Comment: YES . but the dataset has only 12 columns ( not 14 ) . Also it seems like the fread method has converted the colnames ( DT[1,] = 11.0  0 71  0 0.260  9.000 4.600 14.0 1.000 1.000 name    1   0  NA )

Comment: looks like the data has no headers at all... why do you want to set the first line of values al colnames?

Comment: also, line 50 of the file provides more than 12 fields (14).. `line50:  ,?,?,77,?,?,?,?,?,2,?,name,2,?`

Comment: i already fixed this minor pb. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

When using `read.csv` from *base* you can set `na.strings = "?"` and `header=FALSE`.

```
Echocardiogram <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data"
  , na.strings = "?", header=FALSE)

str(Echocardiogram)
#'data.frame':   133 obs. of  13 variables:
# $ V1 : num  11 19 16 57 19 26 13 50 19 25 ...
# $ V2 : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V3 : num  71 72 55 60 57 68 62 60 46 54 ...
# $ V4 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V5 : num  0.26 0.38 0.26 0.253 0.16 0.26 0.23 0.33 0.34 0.14 ...
# $ V6 : num  9 6 4 12.1 22 ...
# $ V7 : num  4.6 4.1 3.42 4.6 5.75 ...
# $ V8 : num  14 14 14 16 18 12 22.5 14 16 15.5 ...
# $ V9 : num  1 1.7 1 1.45 2.25 ...
# $ V10: num  1 0.588 1 0.788 0.571 ...
# $ V11: chr  "name" "name" "name" "name" ...
# $ V12: chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
# $ V13: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```